# Why "Data credentials" can't be blank for community connector when using service account to access underlying bigquery data?

Tags: looker-studio

I built a community connector that uses service account to access the bigquery service and it works fine. However, when I was looking at Service.getEffectiveUser() I noticed that this always resolved to my user even when accessing the published report without any session. When I set the "Data credentials" from "Owner" to "Viewer" it asks to login. However, I plan to use a separate token based authentication by passing the token in the connector url parameter. So, is there a way to execute the community connector script without setting Data credentials to Owner or Viewer? Note that I already return AuthTypes.NONE for getAuthType.

Note that this community connector will not be published and will only be used for a SAAS application where the report will be embedded and accessible to the users of the SAAS application.